# Colimit of Grothendieck topoi

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, topos-theory

Let me preface this by saying that I am a simple man, with simple needs, and I would appreciate

a) no modifications to the question unless strictly necessary (but please let me know if I need to change something to make it sensible/have a reasonable answer),

b) as simple of an answer as is possible.

Suppose that I have an indexed collection of sites $\{\mathcal{C}_i\}_{i\in I}$ (by a site I mean a category with a Grothendieck pre-topology) where $I$ is some index category. Suppose that for every morphism $f\colon i\to j$ in $I$ I have a morphism of topoi

$$(f_\ast,f^\ast)\colon \mathbf{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_i)\to\mathbf{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_j),$$

which is something like a lax $2$-functor (for $i\xrightarrow{f}j\xrightarrow{g}k$ I have chosen equivalences $(g\circ f)^\ast=f^\ast\circ g^\ast$ and $(g\circ f)_\ast= g_\ast\circ f_\ast$ satisfying 'reasonable compatibility conditions'). I can then form the $2$-limit

$$2\text{-lim}\, \mathbf{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_i),$$

with respect to the pullback functors $f^\ast$. My question is whether or not this is naturally $\mathbf{Sh}(\mathcal{C})$ for some reasonable site $\mathcal{C}$. I strongly suspect this is related to the existence of colimits in $\mathbf{ShTopos}$, as in a paper of Moerdijk, but I find that to be too jargony for me. It could, be related to the colimit of [sites](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EXI), but this seems slightly wrong to me.

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: I believe the short answer is that the colimit exists (if the diagram is small) in the category of sheaf toposes and the underlying category is given by the limit of the corresponding diagram of inverse image functors.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks! I think I know this to be abstractly true from the cited result of Moerdijk. I guess what I am more interested in is the question of whether I can naturally build a site $\mathcal{C}$ from the $\mathcal{C}_i$ whose topos produces this $2$-limit over inverse image functors.

Comment: The obvious thing to try is the limit of the corresponding diagram of  morphisms of sites (as a diagram of categories and functors). But the section of Stacks you cite takes the colimit instead. (Incidentally, I see you’re in Tokyo too.)

Comment: @ZhenLin Can you explain a bit more? I find the Stacks Project reference confusing -- I agree what I want is maybe like a limit of sites, and so a colimit of the underlying objects, right? Like the kind of phenomenon I want to capture is that if $X$ is an increasing union of $U_i$ then sheaves on $X$ are compatible families of sheaves on the $U_i$, and that if I take the site whose objects are opens in some $U_i$ and open covers are the open covers in that $U_i$, this seems like a 'colimit of objects and covers' (which is what the Stacks Project seems to be doing for this colimit of sites)

Comment: No, I do mean the limit of the diagram of underlying categories. There seems to be a lack of agreement about what direction morphisms of sites should be but here I am taking them to be same direction as the underlying functor. (I left academia at the end of my PhD. I work in Tokyo now, but I would be happy to discuss this question in person.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow me the use of "jargon".
Let $\textbf{Topos}$ be the 2-category of sheaf toposes.
(A bit more explicitly: the objects are categories satisfying Giraud's axioms and the morphisms $f : \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ are functors $f^* : \mathcal{Y} \to \mathcal{X}$ that preserve colimits and finite limits, and the 2-cells are the natural transformations of such functors.)

**Lemma 1.**
If a diagram $\mathcal{X} : \mathcal{I} \to \textbf{Topos}$ has a colimit, then the underlying category of that diagram is the limit of the diagram $\mathcal{X} : \mathcal{I}^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{Cat}$ of underlying categories.

*Proof.*
Let $\mathcal{O} = [\textbf{FinSet}, \textbf{Set}]$.
It can be shown that, for any sheaf topos $\mathcal{X}$, the category of geometric morphisms $\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{O}$ is equivalent to the underlying category of $\mathcal{X}$ itself, 2-naturally in $\mathcal{X}$.
In other words, the "underlying category" 2-functor $\textbf{Topos}^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{Cat}$ is represented by $\mathcal{O}$.
But representable functors preserve any limits that exist, so colimits in $\textbf{Topos}$ must be limits in $\textbf{Cat}$.　◼

In the very simplest cases, it is easy to give an explicit site for the colimit.
(However, we do have to use here the more general notion of site where we do not require the underlying category to have pullbacks.)

**Proposition 2.**
Coproducts exist in $\textbf{Topos}$.

*Proof.*
The obvious construction works: choose sites for each of the summands, then form the sheaf topos over their disjoint union.　◼

**Proposition 3.**
Tensors exist in $\textbf{Topos}$.

*Proof.*
Again, there is an obvious construction.
By lemma 1, if the tensor of the topos $\textbf{Psh} (\mathcal{C})$ by a small category $\mathcal{I}$ exists, then it must be $\textbf{Psh} (\mathcal{I}^\textrm{op} \times \mathcal{C})$, because:
$$[\mathcal{I}, \textbf{Psh} (\mathcal{C})] \cong [\mathcal{I} \times \mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] \cong \textbf{Psh} (\mathcal{I}^\textrm{op} \times \mathcal{C})$$
In general, the tensor of $\textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{C})$ by $\mathcal{I}$ is $\textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{I}^\textrm{op} \times \mathcal{C})$, where the covering sieves of $\mathcal{I}^\textrm{op} \times \mathcal{C}$ are those whose projections to $\mathcal{C}$ are covering sieves in $\mathcal{C}$.　◼

However, it seems to me in general we have to appeal to Giraud's theorem to show that the candidate category is a sheaf topos, rather than finding an explicit site.
(In some sense, though, finding a site is as hard as showing that Giraud's axioms are satisfied: after all, the full subcategory spanned by the small generating set in Giraud's axioms is a site of definition for the topos.
But in practice we can appeal to black box theorems to get generators, so we cannot so easily extract a site from the proof.)

**Proposition 4.**
Pushouts (in the bicategorical sense) exist in $\textbf{Topos}$.

*Proof.*
Let $f : \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ and $g : \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Z}$ be geometric morphisms.
Suppose we have a pullback diagram in $\textbf{Cat}$ (in the bicategorical sense):
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{W} @>{k^*}>> \mathcal{Y} \\
@V{h^*}VV @VV{f^*}V \\
\mathcal{Z} @>>{g^*}> \mathcal{X}
\end{CD}$$
It is straightforward to check that the category $\mathcal{W}$ satisfies the exactness part of Giraud's axioms, and that the functors $h^* : \mathcal{W} \to \mathcal{Z}$ and $k^* : \mathcal{W} \to \mathcal{Z}$ preserve colimits  and finite limits.
It can also be shown – e.g. using the theory of locally presentable categories – that $\mathcal{W}$ has a small generating set.
So $\mathcal{W}$ is also a sheaf topos, and we have geometric morphisms $h : \mathcal{Z} \to \mathcal{W}$ and $k : \mathcal{Z} \to \mathcal{W}$.
Then we have to check that $\mathcal{W}$ has the appropriate universal property with respect to geometric morphisms, but this is also straightforward.　◼

**Corollary 5.**
Colimits (in the bicategorical sense) exist in $\textbf{Topos}$.　◼

---

I suppose I should give an example to illustrate that things really are tricky.
Let $\mathbb{Z}\textbf{-Set}$ be the category of sets equipped with a $\mathbb{Z}$-action.
Then we have a pullback diagram (in the bicategorical sense) in $\textbf{Cat}$ of the form below,
$$\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}\textbf{-Set} @>>> \textbf{Set} \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\textbf{Set} @>>> \textbf{Set} \times \textbf{Set}
\end{CD}$$
where both arrows $\mathbb{Z}\textbf{-Set} \to \textbf{Set}$ are the forgetful functor and both arrows $\textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Set} \times \textbf{Set}$ are the diagonal embedding.
These categories are all presheaf toposes and these functors are all inverse image functors of geometric morphisms, and (appealing to lemma 1 and proposition 4) this corresponds to a pushout diagram (in the bicategorical sense) in $\textbf{Topos}$.

But $\textbf{Set}$ is the category of sheaves on a point $\{ * \}$, and $\textbf{Set} \times \textbf{Set}$ is the category of sheaves on two points $\{ a, b \}$, and the diagonal embedding corresponds to the unique continuous map $2 \to 1$, so we have a "canonical" representation of the inverse image functor $\textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Set} \times \textbf{Set}$ by a morphism of sites, namely the map $\{ \emptyset, \{ * \} \} \to \{ \emptyset, \{ a \}, \{ b \}, \{ a, b \} \}$ sending $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$ and $\{ * \}$ to $\{ a, b \}$.
It is not at all obvious to me how to extract anything resembling $\mathbb{Z}$ from this morphism of sites.
In the first place, the "canonical" generator of $\mathbb{Z}\textbf{-Set}$ –  $\mathbb{Z}$ with its self-action – is mapped to an object in $\textbf{Set}$ not even in the site we chose.
In the comments I speculated that taking the limit of the diagram of sites would be a candidate site, but this example shows it does not work.

Comment: Thank you for writing this all up!! I will read it carefully tonight. The fact that there somehow isn't a 'simple' site which you can build is slightly dissapointing, but I guess it is what it is. 

Let me ask a related question. This could be contained implicitly in your answer, or perhaps could need a new question to resolve. Is there at least some sort of 'recognition' property for when a site $\mathcal{C}$ might serve as a site with the correct topos (i.e. the limit of the topoi along inverse image)? Namely, suppose that I have a category $\mathcal{C}$ and each of the categories

Comment: $\mathcal{C}_i$ from my original question are (possibly not full) subcategories of $\mathcal{C}$ with the induced site structure, and such that the pullback maps between $\mathcal{C}_i$ and $\mathcal{C}_j$ is compatible with restriction from $\mathcal{C}$. I then obtain from restriction a morphism $\mathbf{Sh}(\mathcal{C})\to \text{2-lim} \mathbf{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_i)$. Is there some simple condition on the $\mathcal{C}_i$ and $\mathcal{C}$ such that I know that this is an equivalence (i.e. that $\mathcal{C}$ is the correct site)? To give an example of what I mean, if $X$ is a topological space

Comment: and $X=\bigcup_n U_n$ is a rising union of open subsets, then we have the above situation with $\mathcal{C}=\mathrm{Open}(X)$ and $\mathcal{C}_i=\mathrm{Open}(U_i)$, and in this case it is true that the map $\mathbf{Sh}(X)\to \text{2-lim} \mathbf{Sh}(U_n)$ is an equivalence. How do I recognize such a situation?

Comment: The case with topological spaces (or locales) is very special, I think, because these toposes have a "canonical" site of definition that is even functorial in geometric morphisms. But even so in the example above the "inputs" to the colimit are toposes of sheaves on topological spaces but the "output" is not, so if there is a recognition principle it must be rather subtle...

Comment: Hmm, I see. Thanks for your hard work. Would you be offended if I posted this also on MO to see if there is any additional thought there?

Comment: You could do that too. (With questions of this level I would probably post on MO first.)